# Custom download directory

Tags: android, download, directory

My app already creates a custom directory, preferably in the external storage:

```
public static File downloadDir;
public static String downloadStorage;
public static String downloadSubPath;

public static void checkDownloadDir(String subPath) {
        String downloadPath = "";
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            downloadStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        } else {
            downloadStorage = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;
        }
        downloadSubPath = subPath;
        downloadPath = downloadStorage + File.separator + downloadSubPath;
        downloadDir = new File(downloadPath);
        if (!downloadDir.exists()) {
            //Log.d("Directory", "creating directory");
            if (downloadDir.mkdirs()) {
                //Log.d("Directory", "directory created");
            } else {
                //Log.d("Directory", "directory not created");
            }
        } else {
            //Log.d("Directory", "directory exists");
        }
    }
```

After the custom folder (downloadSubPath) is created in the available storage (downloadStorage), how can i use this custom path (downloadStorage + File.separator + downloadSubPath, or downloadDir.getPath()) to save files the end user can download?. The files the user can download can be in any format, .pdf, .jpg, .mp4, .doc, etc. Or move the downloaded file from the default save directory to target directory?

Comment: `downloadStorage = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;`. That is silly code. That will never work. You could as well have written `downloadStorage = "Download"; `.

Comment: `custom path (downloadStorage + File.separator + downloadSubPath, or downloadDir.getPath()) to s` Mygod... tell full path instead of those variable names.

Comment: Further your question is strange. If you have a folder you can put any file in it. Or download any file to it. What is the problem?

Comment: @greenapps the multiple variables are for a list of option the user can have on where to save the downloaded file, the variables are used in different parts of the app. The user can create more folders, inside downloadSubPath (The base folder for easy access), so a download path could be also downloadStorage + File.separator + downloadSubPath + File.separator + newFolder. Forget about the variables, how can i save any type of file in a custom folder. Download manager doesn't solve my need.

Comment: `Forget about the variables` Indeed. Tell their value. Tell the full paths that are possible.

Comment: @greenapps besides:
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            downloadStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        } else {
            downloadStorage = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;
        }

all other variables could be any string. File.separator is "/", that is the idea of a custom download folder.

Comment: And you still did not tell full paths.